# finding out number off occurences when a diff() between a 'Time" field is <= 60 seconds in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

EDITED QUESTION:

Got it to work for a different dataset:

```
In [182]: df1
Out[182]:
    Send_Location_ID           Send_Time
0         10000000246622 2016-07-07 06:35:04
1         10000000993388 2016-07-07 17:14:37
2         10000000993388 2016-07-07 17:14:41
3         10000001275259 2016-07-07 10:36:43
4         10000001448034 2016-07-07 10:36:46
5         10000001405702 2016-07-07 07:29:04
6         10000001405702 2016-07-07 17:15:24
7         10000001405702 2016-07-07 17:16:19
8         10000001405702 2016-07-07 17:17:42
9         10000000993388 2016-07-07 10:22:14
10        10000000215994 2016-07-07 06:35:49
11        10000001405702 2016-07-07 00:41:37
12        10000000243481 2016-07-07 11:20:17
13        10000000098764 2016-07-07 11:23:00
```

What I am really after is finding out is the number of occurrences for a particular Location_ID when the   difference between consecutive Send_Time  is <= 60 secs:

```
In [188]:  df3 =    df1.assign(time_diff=df1['Send_Time']).groupby('Send_Location_ID')['Send_Time'].apply(lambda x : x.diff()<=dt.timedelta(seconds=60))

In [189]: df3
Out[189]:
0          False
1          False
2          False
3          False
4          False
5           True
6          False
7           True
8          False
9          False
10         False
11          True
```

So , in the above result set the column that I used to groupby() i.e. Location_ID is not getting retained:

Comment: It works fine with the sample dataset on Python 3.5, pandas 0.18.1. It also worked with Python 2.7 and pandas 0.18.0. Can you reproduce this with the sample you provided here?

Comment: Works fine for me as well `2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)`; pandas `0.18.1`

Comment: @piRSquared Please see the modified question. Thanks

Comment: @piRSquared any inputs for such a solution?